# TASM Print characters of string

Tags: windows, assembly, tasm

I'm trying to print a string character by character, iterating through it. This is what I've got:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA
    string DB 'Something',0
    len equ $-string

.CODE

    xor bx, bx    
    mov si, offset string
Char:
    mov al, byte[si + bx]
    inc bx
    cmp bx, len
    je Fin

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, al
    int 21h

    jmp Char

Fin:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END
```

I don't know if I'm getting the right mem reference of string, because it only shows me weird symbols. I tried adding 30 to dl, thinking it was because of the ascii representation.

How can I print char by char?

Comment: Try changing `.DATA` to `.CODE`.

Comment: @RossRidge Tried, but getting still weird symbols output

Comment: Ok, try the following two lines at the start of your code `mov ax,@data; mov ds,ax`. You'll need to undo the previous change I suggested.

Comment: LOL thanks, for some weird reason I was writting: mov dx, ax, not ds. Thanks, now working :)!! @RossRidge
Post it an I can mark you as an answer :)

Comment: You are missing the code entry point when linking (how do compile your code?). I need to add a label before the first instruction (eg: `start:` then add it to the `END` directive: `END start` else `tlink` complains `Fatal: No program entry point`

Comment: Also, you are `inc`ing bx too early before printing the first char, so the initial `S` is not shown. That must be why you are adding a final `0` to the data: as you are looping yourself to put one char at a time, it does not need to be zero-terminated.

Comment: actually, the missing `S` is due to the notation `byte[si + bx]` with Tasm: it results in the following assembly: `mov al, [bx+si+1]`. Explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36748562/317266)

Comment: @Seki Ohh yeah, I noticed the bx inc cause it was printing from char[0+1], so I checked and I moved inc after printing jaja :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example with Tasm, that is not mangling the begining of the string.

It has one less jump due to the moving of the increment later and the replacement of the `je` with a `jnz`

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA
    string DB 'Something'
    len equ $-string

.CODE

Entry:
    mov ax, @data   ;make DS point to our DATA segment
    mov ds, ax

    xor bx, bx      ;bx <-- 0
    mov si, offset string ;address of string to print

    mov ah, 2       ;we will use repeatedly service #2 of int 21h

Char:
    mov dl, [si + bx] ;dl is the char to print
    int 21h         ;ask DOS to output a single char

    inc bx          ;point to next char
    cmp bx, len     
    jnz Char        ;loop if string not finished

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h         ;DOS exit program with al = exit code

END Entry
```

Comment: You can move the `mov ah, 2` outside the loop above `Char:` since `int 21h/ah=2` only destroys _AL_ (the last character printed is returned in _AL_).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Indeed. I have modified the program in that way, with additional comments.

Comment: No problem. I only quickly glanced at it before. I noticed this as I stumbled on this Q again this evening. `mov al, [si + bx]` `mov dl, al` can be reduced to `mov dl, [si + bx]`