# mov al, byte[si + bx] becomes mov al, [bx+si+1]

Tags: assembly, tasm

While trying to provide a full working (debugged) example for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731384/tasm-print-characters-of-string), I cannot understand the assembled code. I am a bit rusty with the good old DOS + TASM combination.

This is my asm code (`print.asm`):

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA
    string DB 'Something'
    len equ $-string

.CODE

Entry:
    mov ax, @data   ;make DS point to our DATA segment
    mov ds, ax

    xor bx, bx    
    mov si, offset string

Char:
    mov al, byte[si + bx]
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, al
    int 21h

    inc bx
    cmp bx, len
    jnz Char

Fin:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

END Entry
```

I assemble with

```
tasm print.asm
tlink print.obj
```

resulting in the 16bit executable `print.exe`.

When testing, i am surprised to see that the program outputs

```
omething
```

When I look at the assembled object, I can see:

```
_TEXT:0000 start:
_TEXT:0000                 mov     ax, seg DGROUP
_TEXT:0003                 mov     ds, ax
_TEXT:0005                 xor     bx, bx
_TEXT:0007                 mov     si, offset unk_10030
_TEXT:000A
_TEXT:000A loc_1001A:                              ; CODE XREF: _TEXT:0017j
_TEXT:000A                 mov     al, [bx+si+1]   ; <== I do not understand the '+1'
_TEXT:000D                 mov     ah, 2
_TEXT:000F                 mov     dl, al
_TEXT:0011                 int     21h             ; DOS - DISPLAY OUTPUT
_TEXT:0011                                         ; DL = character to send to standard output
_TEXT:0013                 inc     bx
_TEXT:0014                 cmp     bx, 9
_TEXT:0017                 jnz     short loc_1001A
_TEXT:0019                 mov     ax, 4C00h
_TEXT:001C                 int     21h             ; DOS - 2+ - QUIT WITH EXIT CODE (EXIT)
_TEXT:001C                                         ; AL = exit code
```

and I am puzzled with the generated `mov     al, [bx+si+1]` from my `mov al, byte[si + bx]` that points 1 byte from the begining of the string.

Comment: I assume the `byte` is `1` (ie. size of a byte) and some assemblers allow offsets outside of the brackets (so that it resembles array indexing). `al` already implies `byte` so no need to write that out, but if you want it should probably be `byte ptr`.

Comment: @Jester: removing the `byte` fixed the "bug". I always though that `byte` `word` and al when assessing memory were used advice for assembler to use the correct opcodes and not used in offset compute. Though it was more often `byte ptr`.

Comment: You might want to consider using TASM's Ideal mode. It's interpreting BYTE as 1 in order to be compatible with MASM 5. In Ideal mode it would give an error. You'd have rewrite much of the code however, pretty much all of the directives though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`byte[si + bx]` is NASM syntax. In TASM syntax that's equivalent to `[si + bx + byte]`, which is equal to `[si + bx + 1]`.

In the TASM manual in the section "Expressions" you've got a table named "Standard symbol values" where you can see that the symbol "BYTE" corresponds to the value 1.

What you want is `byte ptr [si + bx]`. Or you can simply use `[si + bx]` in this case since there's no ambiguity (because the size of `al` is known to the assembler).

Comment: I do have the Tasm 5 manual. Thanks for that pointer and for disambiguation with the more usual nasm syntax.